# How can I reference a file in my drawable folder to put in WebView in android?

Tags: android, file, reference, webview

For example, I want to make an image appear in webview to utilize the zoom functions.
I would use this line of code:

```
this.myWebView.loadUrl("file://");
```

I just need to know what to put after file to reference the image.

Answer (score 0):

you would have to use the data uri and base64 encode the image bytes. the Uri would look something like this:

```
this.myWebView.loadUrl("data:image/png;base64,<base64DataHere>");
```